# react-i18next: How can I get text in a language, that is not my current selected one?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have the following problem: I use react with i18next and also use i18next-backend to load my translation-files. I have a languageSwitcher that I want to use not only to change the language but also to change the URL.
But I need to access the namespace 'routes' of the new language before changing the language.
How can I do this?

This is my i18n config:

```js
i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(detector)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .init({
    defaultNS: 'routes',
    fallbackLng: ['de'],
    supportedLngs: ['de', 'en'],

    detection: {
      order: ['path'],
      lookupFromPathIndex: 0,
    },
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },

    keySeparator: false,

    interpolation: {
      format,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

My Langugage Selector uses this function:

```js
changeLanguage = (ln) => {
  const routes = i18n.getResourceBundle(i18n.language, 'routes');
  const currentPathname = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, '');
  let currentRouteKey = Object.keys(routes).find((key) => routes[key] === currentPathname);
  if (ln === 'en' && currentPathname === '') {
    currentRouteKey = '/en';
  }
  window.location.replace(this.props.t('routes:' + currentRouteKey, { lng: ln }));
};
```

German is my fallback language and the language change works when I start on the english version of my application, but it doesn't work when I start from the german version. I guess that's because the english file isn't loaded. How can I trigger this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of full page reload (using `location.replace`) you can trigger [`i18next.changeLangauge`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage) to change the language, at the background the lib will load the missing language, and then you can use the [History Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) to change the URL.

```js
// pseudo code

changeLanguage = (ln) => {
  i18n.changeLanguage(lng, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        // handle language change error
      }

      const pathnameParts = window.location.pathname.split("/");
      const currentLangPath = pathnameParts[1]; // skips the first slash
      let newPathnameParts = pathnameParts;
      if (i18n.options.supportedLngs.includes(currentLangPath)) {
        newPathnameParts = newPathnameParts.slice(2); // removes the lang part
      }

      newPathnameParts = [lngSubPaths[lng]].concat(
        newPathnameParts.filter(Boolean)
      );

      const newPathname = newPathnameParts.join("/");

      if (newPathname !== window.location.pathname) {
        window.history.pushState(null, "", newPathname);
      }
    });
};
```

Working [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-forked-c5kvn?file=/src/app.js)